# Doubt in an example of sequence using $\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I have to prove the following
$\frac{2n² - 5}{3n²+7n} = 2/3$ ....
How do I solve it for n? Right now I'm stuck at $\frac{15+14n}{3(3n²+7n)}$$ < \epsilon$
Note : My problem is that I don't understand how to isolate n

Comment: That fraction is not $2/3$. I think you've left out something about a limit ...

Comment: No sir , I've rechecked the problem it's same

Comment: I think the OP was implying the limit of the expression as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is $\frac{2}{3}$ which it is @EthanBolker

Comment: Could you upvote mine as well if it suits you! My solution. It uses L’Hospitals rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to isolate $n$ in that expression. You can note that
$$
\dfrac{15+14n}{3n^2+7n}\leq \dfrac{15n}{3n^2} = \frac 5n
$$

and then argue that
$$
\frac 5n < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \dfrac{15+14n}{3n^2+7n} < \varepsilon.
$$

Comment: Dear Sir , I have one doubt , would using inequality ≤ affect the epsilon and positive integer m ( the value we take greater than epsilon) value

Comment: @Mr.AlvinRocks You can use the $\leq$ for the upper bound but must use $<$ when computing $m$ for a fixed $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I see , thanks sir